# Pdf generation using itext for Bangla text in android

Tags: java, android, pdf, fonts, itext

I am using i-text for generating `pdf` from my android application. But it worked fine for English fonts. When I was trying to generate `pdf` for my locale, Bangla, I got some problems. After getting some tips from some blog I have got the implementation in the way mentioned bellow:

```
String fontName = "Nikosh.ttf";
    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(fontName);
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    int a = is.read(buffer);
    BaseFont customFont = BaseFont.createFont(fontName, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, true, buffer, buffer);
    Font banglaFont = new Font(customFont, 12);
```

Now the output looks like this:

This is the output for Bangla text using a bangla font

[image]

But the output text is broken. Whereas the original one looks like this one:

Original text in Bangla

[image: image2]

Any help regarding how to solve this type of problem for unicode in android would be highly appreciated.
N.B. I am using i-text 5.5.x

Comment: You are using iText 5 or earlier. It is normal that the output is broken, since iText 5 doesn't support Bangla text. If you want support for Indic languages, you need to upgrade to iText 7 and use the [pdfCalligraph add-on](https://itextpdf.com/itext7/pdfcalligraph). Read the [pdfCalligraph white paper](https://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/attachments/Whitepaper_pdfCalligraph_2017.pdf) for more info. iText 7 has the same license as iText 5, but pdfCalligraph has been kept closed source to avoid abuse.

Answer (score 0):

Use font that display as well.

```
BaseFont base = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf", BaseFont.WINANSI);
Font font = new Font(base, 11f, Font.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this library :

```
implementation 'com.uttampanchasara.pdfgenerator:pdfgenerator:1.3'
```

minsdk :

```
above 21
```